# Multithreaded Inferences on LLM using GPU's

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, large-language-model

If I call the LLM inference (`infer()` in this case) parallely using multiple threads on a single instance of a model (which consumes all the GPU's), will that work?

Code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

checkpoint = "WizardLM/WizardCoder-15B-V1.0"
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"  # "cuda:X" for GPU usage or "cpu" for CPU usage


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Running in " + device)
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
        self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint, device_map='auto')

    def infer(self, input_text, token_count):
        inputs = self.tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
        outputs = self.model.generate(inputs, max_new_tokens=token_count)
        return self.tokenizer.decode(outputs[0])
```

Why I am asking this is as: During the minute long inferences (p3.8x-large EC2) I observe that although GPU memory is consumed fully but the % utilisation is low.

Edit: Calling infer() for same object of Model works and GPU usage is also high, but I am still unclear that if: tokenizer/model are threadsafe?

I found this: https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/issues/3672
But this does not confirm anything.